# determine last item in for each from a database

Tags: .net, vb.net, foreach

This will be a possible duplicate, but I can't solve it. I am iterating each data from the database / dataTable then display it using forEach. Though I want to do something on the `first` and `last` item.

```
For Each dtrow In gpsDtable.Rows
        If ReferenceEquals(Collection.Item(Collection.Count - 1), dtrow) Then
            'do something for the last item in loop
            'I also want to do something for the first item
        End If
    'do things in loop
 Next
```

Just saw this code snippet somewhere.. And  I get this error

```
Reference to a non share member requires an object reference.
```

As I am not quite sure what does it mean, so I'm going to ask..
Please do re-write the code if its wrong. Actually, the if statement is an error :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, the snippet is not an exact code. You expected to change `Collection.Item` and `Collection.Count` with your own Collection variable (`gpsDtable.Rows` in this case), for example :

```
For Each dtrow In gpsDtable.Rows
    If ReferenceEquals(gpsDtable.Rows(gpsDtable.Rows.Count - 1), dtrow) Or ReferenceEquals(gpsDtable.Rows(0), dtrow) Then
        'do something for the last and first item in loop
    End If
    'do things in loop
Next
```

Or if you prefer using `foreach` loop with counter to determine first and last iteration, then I think it is the same as using standard for loop :

```
For i As Integer = 0 To gpsDtable.Rows.Count - 1
    If i = 0 Or i = gpsDtable.Rows.Count - 1 Then
        'do something for the first and last item in loop
    End If
    'do things in loop
Next
```

Comment: this, I think is the answer to my question. But I used the other answer. thank you anyway

Comment: It's ok. I added my opinion, which solution/answer to choose is up to you

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim  i as Integer
For Each dtrow In gpsDtable.Rows
If i =0 Then
'Do Something
Else If i = gpsDtable.Rows.count-1 Then
'Do Something
End If
i=i+1
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You have referenced a non-shared member within your code and failed to supply an object reference. You cannot use the class name itself to qualify a member that is not shared. The instance must first be declared as an object variable and then referenced by the variable name